# Serializing an Enum that implements an interface with Gson

Tags: java, gson

I have some library code that I need to serialize. One field is defined as an interface Foo, which is simply a marker interface.  Client code is supposed to create an Enum that implements `Foo`, so that they can extend the subtype list as needed.

I'm unable to serialize this in Gson with a type adaptor. The exception I get is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "SETUP"

where setup is one element of the client enumeration `Bar`.

I have added a `TypeAdapter` that defines `Foo` as the supertype and `Bar` as the subtype, using the Gson `RuntimeTypeAdapter` code (a Gson helper from Google).  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong, or is this kind of structure just not supported by Gson?

I believe I can work around by making `Foo` an abstract class and `Setup` be a subclass, but that's a little less good since the enum is really just a token.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd post the exception stacktrace at least for the very cause, a MCVE and the version of Gson you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is related to the fact that since you are implementing an interface Gson expects a class but gets an enum instead. This may be a bug, I'll have to take a deeper look at it.

In any case, I think the best solution to your problem could be implementing a custom serializer/deserializer for the annotation. Your interface will require subclasses to implement a name() method (which you should have already implemented since it's an enum) and then call that to do the serialization.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyInterfaceSerializer implements JsonSerializer<MyInterface> {

public JsonElement serialize(MyInterface src, Type typeOfSrc,
        JsonSerializationContext context) {

    return context.serialize(src.name());
}
```

The deserialization is basically the same but the deserializer (could and should be the same class) will implement `JsonDeserializer` and instantiate your enum.

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce the error the OP gets? I could reproduce neither for a class mapping nor for a single enum value.

Comment: "Gson expects an object but gets an enum instead" an enum is an Object

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I couldn't, but I don't know which version of Gson he is using.

Comment: @Aurasphere LOL an enum is also a class :-). At runtime, there is almost nothing to distinguish an enum from any old other object. It's just compiler sugar.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd you can find out if a class is an anum at runtime if you use instanceof. And I suspect that's exactly the OP problem.

Comment: @Aurasphere I know and I agree with your conclusions, just not with the wording

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I'm sorry, I'm not good at wording... This is why I'm a programmer and not a poet :P ahaha

Comment: btw, the last line won't compile, unless the interface has a name() method. But you can replace it with `return context.serialize(Enum.class.cast(src).name());`

Comment: "Your interface will require subclasses to implement a name() method (which you should have already implemented since it's an enum) and then call that to do the serialization." Yep, that's what I meant here

Comment: ah sorry, missed that

Comment: No problem, there may be other errors though, since I wrote it on the fly and I can't test it on this computer, so it's good to have a review! Thank you!